# Error using lambda sort

Tags: web2py

I'm relatively new to web2py, and having problems with this sort function:

```
sorted_rows = day_rows.sort(lambda r: r.inspection)
```

This results in the error:

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'> <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

day_rows is the result from a database select, and has, in this case, about 20 rows in it.

I clearly am missing something elementary, but I can't figure it out. I will greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you converted day_rows to a list of dictionaries (so it is no longer a DAL Rows object), perhaps doing something like `db(db.mytable).select().as_list()`. In that case, you are calling the `sort()` method of a standard Python `list` object, for which the second argument is "cmp", which takes two arguments. If you want to keep day_rows as a list, you can do:

```
day_rows.sort(key=lambda r: r['inspection'])
```

Though that will sort the list in place rather than returning a new list. If you want a new list, do:

```
sorted_rows = sorted(day_rows, key=lambda r: r['inspection'])
```

Otherwise, leave day_rows as a DAL `Rows` object, and your original code should work.

Comment: Yep, your suggestion worked perfectly. Now I'll go back and figure out where the DAL Rows object got changed; it's not immediately apparent to me. Thanks very much for your help. Web2py is pretty powerful, bu there is a learning curve...

Comment: Can you show the code where day_rows is created, as well as any code that operates on it? Did you use `executesql()`?

Comment: I was, indeed, doing something that changed to Rows to a list - obvious when I took a fresh look at it this morning. Your response led me right to it.